# Display: flex element wont grow vertically within parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a webpage where I want to center one of the pages both vertically and horizontally, like that:

```
<main>
  <div>
    This has to be centered both vertically and horizontally.
  </div>
</main>
```

I can't change display of `main` as it's widely used for all the pages, and using `flex` there breaks way too much stuff.

I assumed this should work but it does not, because `div` does not grow in height:

```
main {
  min-height: 1000px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I'd rather not do `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`.

Any hints how can I stretch my `div` to fill `main`? Why wouldn't it work out of the box, can't `flex` simply grow within elements with `block/inline-block` displays?

https://jsfiddle.net/wcu6fnz5/

Comment: flex-grow is useless because it need the parent to have display;flex, not the element itself

Comment: It actually does not matter at this point, the flex grow was added only because if it had flex parent it'd grow vertically, right now it does nothing as you pointed out. I guess flex is basically useless when used inside of block/inline-block elements? Eh...

Comment: display: flex; should always be applied on parent

Comment: *I can't change display of main as it's widely used for all the pages* --> Use ID/classes for some specific cases. This sounds like a design/conception issue rather than a CSS one

Comment: @TemaniAfif I get your point. That would've been a bit easier, but I don't control nor use classes at all in this project, styled components. Oh, technology.

Comment: add more context to your question then. Probably knowing that it's a styled components will make us thing of better answers

Answer (score 0):

The thing about flexbox is that you should focus on instructing the parent, not the child.

In your example, `justify-content` and `display: flex` should be in the parent. You could also use `flex-direction: column` to tell the browser you want the child to grow vertically.

You could also use `flex: 1` as a shorthand for flex-grow. This way, the child doesn't even need `display: flex`.

```css
main {
  min-height: 1000px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

### Update

To achieve what you mentioned in the comments, why don't you try this:

```css
main {
  min-height: 1000px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

section {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  background: gainsboro;

  /* important stuff */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  width: 40px;
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

Those sizes and colors are only for you to see the results.

Comment: Upvoted. So, my question is - could I somehow put a flex-parent inside of `main` and then use div within that parent? I've tried that but flex wrapper does not seem to grow as well... I'm thinking something like `<main><section><div></div></section></main>` where `section` has has `flex`. Can't figure it out :/

Comment: @Wordpressor upvotes should be made to *correct* answer not *wrong* one that are contradictory with the question .. actually you will make your question more confusing. So if I povide you with the solution using position:absolute, will you upvote me? if it's the case let me grap the duplicate question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could you elaborate on how my answer is contradictory to the question? I'm literally showing him how to achieve what he wants and explaining how flexbox works.

Comment: he said *I can't change display of main as it's widely used for all the pages, and using flex there breaks way too much stuff.* --> and you have changed the *main* in both of your examples

Comment: @FilipeMerker I feel like your second response was spot on and not at all contradictory, but this does not seem to work at all, are we missing something? Note I dont want to set height on section either, thats why Im using flex. https://jsfiddle.net/qpcvx0Lg/

Comment: @Wordpressor Updated your fiddle. In this case, if you can't touch on main at-all, than you do need some other size reference for flex to follow. Can you make the section as big as main? https://jsfiddle.net/uk4zn73L/

Answer (score 0):

It might helps you.

```css
/* I cannot edit main, there are 100s of pages based on it, cant change its display etc. */

main {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    min-height: inherit;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <span>This has to be centered both vertically and horizontally.</span>
  </div>
</main>
```